# Set grid.row maxheight by binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, resize

I've a WPF application with a main grid  with 4 rows.
I wont to bind the property `MaxHeight` of the row(0) by XAML or code behind to the `Height` value of the control inside.
The control inside row(0) is a `ScrollViewer` and at run time, I add controls inside the SV.

I've tried with the XAML code:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="64" MaxHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=HeaderScrollViewer}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And by code behind :

```
  Grid.SetRow(Me.MainGrid, 0)
  Me.MainGrid.MaxHeight = Me.HeaderScrollViewer.Height
  Me.MainGrid.UpdateLayout()
```

But no luck...any suggestions?

Comment: so u basically want the height of the first row only to be controlled dynamically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147908/how-do-i-databind-a-columndefinitions-width-or-rowdefinitions-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `ActualHeight`.

```
  Grid.SetRow(Me.MainGrid, 0)
  Me.MainGrid.MaxHeight = Me.HeaderScrollViewer.ActualHeight <---
  Me.MainGrid.UpdateLayout()
```

Comment: When I add controls, the grid.row(0).Heigth is setted to "Auto", then the ScrollView I have inside row(0) can expand. At the end of adding operations I have the dimensione of the control. But I can't set the MaxHeigt correctly.In any case, with Heigth property the graphic result is better and I don't know why.