# resizable segment in timeline: bind segment size to view model

Tags: c#, xaml, timeline, avaloniaui

I am trying to implement a user control that represents a timeline (like in a video editor) with a segment whose start- and end-marker can be dragged by the user.

I am representing a segment like this in my view model:

```cs
public class Moment : ViewModelBase
{
    [Reactive] public double From { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public double Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And attempted to implement the view using a grid with grid splitters like this:

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,3,Auto,3,*" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Panel Grid.Column="0" Name="SpacerLeft"
           Width="{Binding From}" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="cyan" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Name="SpacerSegment"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="red" Height="40"
               Width="{Binding Duration}">
    </Rectangle>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Background="cyan" />
    <Panel Grid.Column="4" Name="SpacerRight"/>
</Grid>
```

This works as in I can somewhat visually resize the segment:

[image: timeline drag example gif]

However, I am struggling to get the size changes back into the view model, which you can also see in the red area not changing size. I couldn't find a way to retrieve the width changes of the `SpacerLeft` or `SpacerSegment` controls.

What I tried instead was removing the dedicated `Width` properties and instead binding the grid's `ColumnDefinitions`. I added this property to my view model:

```cs
public ColumnDefinitions ColumnDefinitions
{
    get => ColumnDefinitions.Parse($"{From},3,{Duration},3,*");
    set
    {
        From = value[0].ActualWidth;
        Duration = value[2].ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

and changed the view XAML to this:

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="{Binding ColumnDefinitions}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Panel Grid.Column="0" Name="SpacerLeft" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="cyan" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Name="SpacerSegment"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="red" Height="40">
    </Rectangle>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Background="cyan" />
    <Panel Grid.Column="4" Name="SpacerRight"/>
</Grid>
```

But this fails to compile for a reason that unfortunately doesn't make much sense to me:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Avalonia.Data.Binding' to type 'Avalonia.Controls.ColumnDefinition'. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Avalonia.Data.Binding' to type 'Avalonia.Controls.ColumnDefinition'.
  at Avalonia.Collections.AvaloniaList`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value) in /_/src/Avalonia.Base/Collections/AvaloniaList.cs:line 520
  at Builder_1ee6d795025442edb279bcc7110e88eb_avares://AvaloniaOutseekClient/Views/MomentsSourceView.axaml.XamlClosure_2.Build(IServiceProvider )
  at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.XamlIl.Runtime.XamlIlRuntimeHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<DeferredTransformationFactoryV1>b__0(IServiceProvider sp) in /_/src/Markup/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/XamlIl/Runtime/XamlIlRuntimeHelpers.cs:line 28
  at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Templates.TemplateContent.Load(Object templateContent) in /_/src/Markup/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/Templates/TemplateContent.cs:line 17
  at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Templates.DataTemplate.Build(Object data, IControl existing) in /_/src/Markup/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml/Templates/DataTemplate.cs:line 33
  at Avalonia.Controls.Presenters.ContentPresenter.CreateChild() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/Presenters/ContentPresenter.cs:line 356
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is trying to directly Bind to Grid's `ColumnDefinitions`. Instead, using the long definition form and binding to each column's width directly is the way to go:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ...}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

It also is necessary to explicitly specify `Mode=TwoWay`, as bindings to a `ColumnDefinition`'s width are not two-way by default.

Next, because a `ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` property is actually of type `GridLength` and not `double`, a `IValueConverter` is required as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147908/3688648).

At this point the grid's XAML should look like this

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding From, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Duration, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Panel Grid.Column="0" Name="SpacerLeft" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="cyan" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Name="SpacerSegment"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="red" Height="40">
    </Rectangle>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Background="cyan" />
    <Panel Grid.Column="4" Name="SpacerRight"/>
</Grid>
```

Furthermore, to fix the left grid splitter moving the selection instead of extending it to the left, the `Moment` view model needs to represent the segment with a `From` and `To` property instead of a `From` and `Duration` property, and have the `Duration` property derive from the other two instead. This requires hooking up some property change events by hand instead of relying on `[Reactive]`:

```cs
private double _from;
private double _to;

public double From
{
    get => _from;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_from, value)) 
            return;
        this.RaisePropertyChanging(nameof(Duration));
        this.RaisePropertyChanging();
        _from = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Duration));
    }
}

public double To
{
    get => _to;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_to, value)) 
            return;
        this.RaisePropertyChanging(nameof(Duration));
        this.RaisePropertyChanging();
        _to = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Duration));
    }
}

public double Duration
{
    get => To - From;
    set => To = From + value;
}
```

With these changes the result looks like this:

[image: segment slider demo]